# Too Many Redirects When Loading jQuery in Chrome

Tags: support

Since yesterday when I visit Stack Overflow and Meta I get a red message at the top that says: "Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load."  When I go directly to the link (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js) in Chrome (and Firefox browser) as was suggested in another post I get the following message: "This webpage has a redirect loop".

Everything works fine in IE browser.

Is there something I can do to fix this?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Here is what the network tab in the developer tools is showing:

[image]

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy or firewall?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I am.  And I've never had a problem in the past, though I guess they could've changed something.  But why would it still work in IE?

Comment: It is possible a group policy got pushed to Internet Explorer, but it's not being reflected on Chrome and Firefox. Maybe talk to a IT department to see if there's something up?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow or the software that powers the Stack Exchange network within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: Saw you updated with a screenshot. Looks like you're being redirected through `http://wsa/` without any additional domain information, probably meaning it's inside your corporate firewall. In this context, I'd be willing to bet `wsa` stands for web security appliance. Definitely have a chat with your local IT department and see if you can get it resolved.

Comment: It's resolved.  Thanks for your help Steven.